# nested document field update in mongodb using for loop

Tags: mongodb

While trying this query in mongodb it emits the error like $set is empty. Please provide a solution to rectify

```
var set = {},i,l;

for(i=0,l='Job'.length;i<l;i++)

 {
  if('Job.post.@black'=="true") 

{
set['Job.post.duties.' + i + '.title.@blacklist'] = "false";

 }
}

db.job.update({'id':"19223"},{$set:set})
```

Comment: In case if statement condition is never satisfied then it will not assign any value to variable set. So in this case you might get this error.

Comment: The db.job.update line only emits this error.  The above looping executed successfully. '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} This is my error

Comment: Can you check what is the value of variable set

Comment: before executing db.job.update({'id':"19223"},{$set:set}).

Comment: script executed successfully is the output for that

Comment: The variable part executed successfully. But how to set the varible result into the $set: set

Comment: Can you show us some sample documents from the **`db.job`** collection?

Comment: {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51cff693d342704b5047e6d8"),
            "author" : "test",
            "body" : "sdfkj dsfhk asdfjad ",
            "comments" : [
                    {
                            "author" : "test",
                            "body" : "sdfkjdj\r\nasdjgkfdfj",
                            "email" : "test@tes.com"
                    }],
                         [

                    {
                            "author" : "hola",
                            "body" : "sdfl\r\nhola \r\nwork here"
                    }
                         ]

}

Comment: like this means how i updtae the autgor at a time in  comments[0] and comments[1]